# Windows Feature Update Silent Install

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, windows-update

We are trying to push out the latest Windows Feature update via our RMM but when running it doesn't appear to do anything.  We've tried running the following:

PowerShell
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\Windows10Update.exe -ArgumentList "/quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade"

Shell Command
C:\Windows\Temp\Winodws10Update.exe /quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade

We've run both through a script through the RMM and directly on the workstations in PS ISE and CMD prompt with no luck. I'm assuming I maybe the switches are wrong but I can't find anything to indicate so.  I've also disable the UAC.

Don't see anything apparent in event log erroring out either.

Answer (score 0):

Look like your command contain syntax error, the corrected version would be:

for Powershell: `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\Temp\Windows10Update.exe" -ArgumentList "/quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade"`

and for Command Prompt: `C:\Windows\Temp\Windows10Update.exe /quietinstall /skipeula /auto upgrade`

Also be sure that `Windows10Update.exe` is in `C:\Windows\Temp"`